# Calculate the limit $ \lim_{x\to\infty}\intop_{x}^{2x}\frac{1}{t}\cos\left(\frac{1}{t^{2}}\right)dt $

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to calculate the limit  $ \lim_{x\to\infty}\intop_{x}^{2x}\frac{1}{t}\cos\left(\frac{1}{t^{2}}\right)dt $

Actually I have a way of solution, but this should be a 60 seconds or less answer (from an exam with a lot more questions)

So I wander if there's easier way or I'll just have to think faster.

Here's what I tried:

for $ x\to \infty $ also $ t\to\infty $ and $ \frac{1}{t^{2}}\to\infty $ so we can take taylor expansion of $ cos $ around $ 0 $:

$ \cos\left(x\right)=1-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+R_{3}\left(x\right) $ thus:

$ \cos\left(\frac{1}{t^{2}}\right)=1-\frac{1}{2t^{4}}+R_{3}\left(\frac{1}{t^{2}}\right) $

and also $ |R_{3}\left(x\right)|=|\frac{f^{(4)}\left(x_{0}\right)}{4!}x^{4}|\leq\frac{x^{4}}{4!} $ thus

$ |R_{3}\left(\frac{1}{t^{2}}\right)|\leq\frac{1}{4t^{8}} $

now:

$ \intop_{x}^{2x}\frac{1}{t}\cos\left(\frac{1}{t^{2}}\right)dt=\intop_{x}^{2x}\left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{2t^{5}}+\frac{1}{t}R_{3}\left(\frac{1}{t^{2}}\right)\right)dt=\left(\ln\left(t\right)\right)_{x}^{2x}+\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{1}{t^{4}}\right)_{x}^{2x}+\intop_{x}^{2x}\frac{1}{t}R_{3}\left(\frac{1}{t^{2}}\right)dt $

And  $ |\intop_{x}^{2x}\frac{1}{t}R_{3}\left(\frac{1}{t^{2}}\right)|\leq\intop_{x}^{2x}\frac{1}{4t^{9}}dt=\left(-\frac{1}{32}\cdot\frac{1}{t^{8}}\right)_{x}^{2x}\underset{x\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $

Thus  $ \lim_{x\to\infty}\intop_{x}^{2x}\frac{1}{t}\cos\left(\frac{1}{t^{2}}\right)dt=\ln2 $

It took me quite long time to think about it, if there's easier way/tips or tricks to do it easer, it would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simpler way. If $x$ is large enough then $0\leq 1-\cos (\frac  1 {t^{2}})<\epsilon$ for all $t \in (x,2x)$. Hence $\int_x^{2x} \frac  1 t [1-\cos (\frac  1 {t^{2}})]dt<\epsilon (\ln (2x)-\ln x)=(\ln 2) \epsilon$.  Hence it is enough to find the limit of $\int_x^{2x} \frac  1 t dt $ which is $\ln 2$ by direct calculation.

Comment: Why's the fact that the integral is smaller then $ln2 \varepsilon $ promises that the limit is $ ln2$ ?

Comment: @Waizman Write $\frac 1 t \cos (\frac 1 {t^{2}})$ as $\frac 1 t  -\frac 1 t [1-\cos (\frac 1 {t^{2}})]$  and split into two integrals. I proved that the second integral tends to $0$. So it is enough to find the limit of the first integral which is easy.

Comment: I see, wonderful solution. Thanks